# How do you escape a reserved word in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, syntax, escaping, reserved-words

I need to Escape a reserved word to use it as an identifier in Delphi.  I thought that was accomplished by using the ampersand "&", but that doesn't seem to be working right.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the [doc page](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/fundamentalsyntacticelementsov_xml.html#5468652044656C706869204368617261637465722053657420616E642042617369632053796E746178) (search for **Extended Syntax**) on it, and it should be ampersand.

Figured out the problem.  The ampersand works for compiling and error insight, but not code completion.  Good to know.  I had to add an _ suffix to get code completion to work, then change it back afterwords.  I should check QC for a bug report.

Comment: Another way to refer to identifiers that are reserved words is to use their fully qualified names — include the unit or variable name before the function or property name.