# How do you escape a reserved word in Free-Pascal?

Tags: delphi, lazarus, freepascal

Actually i'am working on translate some librarys to free-pascal. so the problem is which in delphi can use the ampersand (&) symbol to escape a reserved word, but in free-pascal does not work. the compiler complains with this message
`ForLibDx.pas(72,13) Fatal: illegal character "'&'" ($26)`

when include an ampersand symbol.

actually i am using the `{$MODE DELPHI}` to compile my units under free-pascal

FPC 2.2.4

Lazarus 0.9.28.2

thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Using a indentifier or reserved word in a automation object under FPC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501090/using-a-indentifier-or-reserved-word-in-a-automation-object-under-fpc/4502679#4502679)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I recollect, the FPC compiler does not have a means for escaping reserved words.
The ampersand (&) as an escape character to escape reserved words is a Delphi-compiler-only feature of the Delphi language.

You might work around this by using the fully qualified name (including unit, and classname) as Rob Kennedy suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512109/how-do-you-escape-a-reserved-word-in-delphi/1512148#1512148).

NB: It is recommended to avoid these ampersand escapes in Delphi for non-generated code, as not all of the IDE and 3rd party tools can cope with it.

--jeroen

Comment: It does, but only in the development version (2.5.1). http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=18339  Afaik & was mostly added for IDispatch btw? COM objects can have fieldnames/methods that are keywords/reserved words.

Comment: This version is now gold as version 2.6.0