# Using a indentifier or reserved word in a automation object under FPC

Tags: delphi, lazarus, freepascal, ole-automation

Actually i am using OLE automation under Free Pascal , but some objects have properties which uses reserverd words as names, so i cannot compile the code.

check this sample

```
  MyObj : OleVariant;
begin
  MyObj := CrealeOleObject('AObject');
  MyObj.Descriptor   := Param1;
  MyObj.Type            := Param2;  //this line  generates a error
```

this is the error

> StdOleAux.pas(783,15) Fatal: Syntax
>   error, "identifier" expected but
>   "TYPE" found

so the question is how  i can access this properties in  FPC when they have a name which is a reserved word?

FPC 2.2.4

Lazarus 0.9.28.2

using  `{$MODE DELPHI}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you escape a reserved word in Free-Pascal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501002/how-do-you-escape-a-reserved-word-in-free-pascal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need version '2.5.1' of FPC, see the report ["Allow Extended Identifiers in the Delphi mode"](http://62.166.198.202/view.php?id=15930) which has been resolved as fixed at 2010-03-22.